# Read values from looping angular tabular column

Tags: angular7

I have an angular table where table rows and columns are developed from ngfor loop.
[As shown in image my table is currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kROtb.png).So when i clicked on save button we need to iterate through each table row and read the values present in each td and need to store them in object.so please tell how to do develop logic in angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `formGroup` easily.

See this example,
[Table data binding example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-andacc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Hope this example will give you a better understanding rather than explaining all with words.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing your answer, in the above example there is only td from where input value is reading ,can you please tell me example with multiple tds from where value can be read

Comment: The solution provided is not that much use pleaseprovide other solution

Comment: iam getting error of cant read property of getting undefined in forms.js whe i used above example